# what is causing Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 5

Tags: java

```
public static void sumrowsandcols(int[][] a) {

    int[] sum = new int[5];
    int i, j, x;
    // Sum of rows
    for (i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
       for (j = 0; j < 5; j++) {
           sum[i] += a[i][j];
       }
    }
    for (x = 0; x < 5; x++) { 
        System.out.println(sum[x]);
    }

    // Sum of columns
    for (i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
       for (j = 0; j < 5; j++) {
           sum[i] += a[j][i];
       }
    }

    for (x = 0; x < 5; x++) { 
        System.out.println(sum[x]);
    }
  }


  public static int[][] generateArray(Scanner myScanner) {

    int numbers[][] = new int[5][5];
    int i, j, x;
    for (i = 0; i < 5; i++)
      System.out.println("Please enter 5 integers for row " + (i+1));     
      for (x = 0; x < 5; x++) {
        j = myScanner.nextInt();
        numbers[i][x] = j;
      } 
      return numbers;
  }

  // Main method. Collection happens, then calls sumrowsandcols. 

  public static void main(String[] args) {   

    int i, j, x;
    Scanner myScanner = new Scanner(System.in);    
    int[][] numbers = generateArray(myScanner);

    // Collect information by row        


    // Print sum of rows and columns
    sumrowsandcols(numbers);    
   }
```

Comment: Look at the stack trace. Find the line where the exception happens and indicate which line of this code that is. Knowing where the exception happened will help people figure out why it happened.

Comment: I could not find the error, but the code under `Sum of columns` comment look suspicious...

Answer (score 2):

This statement

```
for (i = 0; i < 5; i++)
   System.out.println("Please enter 5 integers for row " + (i + 1));
```

terminates *before* the subsequent `for` loop. As a result `i` has already exceeded the upper bound of the column array index when the statement

```
numbers[i][x] = j;
```

is invoked. The result is an `ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException`. This is why it is important to use braces to delimit scope in `for` loops. Also declaring the variables in the `for` loops themselves show that they are in scope:

```
for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
   System.out.println("Please enter 5 integers for row " + (i + 1));
      for (int x = 0; x < 5; x++) {
         j = myScanner.nextInt();
         numbers[i][x] = j;
      }
}
```

Comment: Correct, you want that for loop to be enclosed in curly braces.

Comment: Probably would have been more obvious had the var i been declared in the loop itself and not before the loop

Comment: Agreed, this will cause the compiler to complain if the variables are out of scope

Answer (score 1):

When you write

```
 for (i = 0; i < 5; i++)
  System.out.println("Please enter 5 integers for row " + (i+1));     '
```

This prints out the statemnt all at once and the other loop is executed after printing it 5 times. put braces after the for loop to group it all.

```
 public static int[][] generateArray(Scanner myScanner) {

    int numbers[][] = new int[5][5];
    int i, j, x;
    for (i = 0; i < 5; i++){
        System.out.println("Please enter 5 integers for row " + (i + 1));
    for (x = 0; x < 5; x++) {
        j = myScanner.nextInt();
        numbers[i][x] = j;
    }
    }
    return numbers;
}
```

Comment: shit i typoed and didn't notice, sorry

Comment: @DanN. That is a very common mistake. Always make it a habit to put braces when you use a for loop.